# Generalization of DiscreteMarkovProcess?

Tags: markov-chains, cellular-automata

I am trying to create a Markov chain using the initial state of a probabilistic cellular automaton, that is a list of length 8, as the first argument of the function `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, and with a second argument of the transition matrix as the cellular automaton moves from state to state, also of length 8.

However, after reading the documentation for `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, I am realizing that this won't work, because the function normalizes the first argument to sum to 1. This means that the resulting argument is a list of length two: `{0,1}`, as opposed to something of the form `{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0}`. So the function fails to evaluate and something like this is returned:

`DiscreteMarkovProcess[{0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0}, {{1,.9,0,.3,.5,0,1,.2}}]
(*DiscreteMarkovProcess[{0,1}, {{1,.9,0,.3,.5,0,1,.2}}]*)`

Is there a better function to use that will allow me to easily generate a Markov chain representation of a probabilistic cellular automaton?

Comment: `DiscreteMarkovProcess` uses first argument as a list of states, and needs a square transition matrix that specifies the probabilities for each combination of states. So you probably need to construct a list of transition matrices for each element in your original list where your probabilities will be off-diagonal elements and then make a list of `DiscreteMarkovProcess` for each element using those matrices.